# circuitikz align tripoles

Tags: circuitikz

I started using tripoles in circuitikz and now I realized I can't get stuff aligned anymore.

A simple example:

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw
  (0,0)
  node[npn](Q1){}
  (Q1.C)
  to[short]
  ++(1,0)
  to[V=${\SI{10}{\volt}}$]
  ++(0,-2.75)
  node[rground]{}

  (Q1.E)
  to[short]
  (0,-2)
  node[rground]{}

  (Q1.B)
  to[short]
  ++(-1, 0)
  to[V=${\SI{0.6}{\volt}}$]
  ++(0, -2)
  node[rground]{}
  ;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

The rground-node below the 10V-Source is misaligned with the others. Is there a simple way to navigate through the circuit, so I get to the same coordinates from each anchor of a tripole?

Comment: ++(0,-2) is a relative coordinate, that is it moves from the current location 2cm down.  (0,-2) is an absolute coordinate (relative to the origin).  If you want them aligned, use absolute coordinates for all three.

Answer (score 2):

Just assign a coordinate to the first gnd-node and reference to it at the following gnd-nodes, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw
  (0,0)  node[npn](Q1){}
  (Q1.C) to[short] ++(1,0) to[V=${\SI{10}{\volt}}$] ++(0,-2.75)
  node[rground](gnd){}
  (Q1.E) to[short]  (Q1.E|-gnd)  node[rground]{}
  (Q1.B) to[short] ++(-1, 0) coordinate(top) to[V=${\SI{0.6}{\volt}}$] (top|-gnd) 
  node[rground]{}
  ;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]